# How to echo submit input form with name of specific id

Tags: php, mysqli

My current code, which does not satisfy my needs, looks like following:

```
<?php 

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "blogs");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM foods order by date desc";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while ($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    //my variables  
    $buttonname = $r['id']; //for name I want to set on submit input on every echo of form of each results. Ps. My id on my database are set to auto increment. 
    $lhtitle = $r['title'];
    $lhcategory = "foods";
    $lhimage = $r['image'];
    $lhtext = $r['text'];


    echo "<div class='content-content'>";
    echo strtoupper("<div class='L-TITLE'>$lhtitle</div>");
    echo "<form action='' method='POST'><input type ='submit' value='Add to Collection' name = '$buttonname'";
    echo "class='addto-button'></form>";
    echo "<div class='content-img'>";
    echo "<img style = 'width:100%;' src='images/$lhimage' alt='no image inserted'>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div class='content-description'><p>$lhtext</p></div>";
    echo "</div>";
}

if (isset($_POST[$buttonname])) {

    $usn = $_SESSION['logged'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `$displayuserid` (title,category,image,text) SELECT '$lhtitle','$lhcategory','$lhimage','$lhtext' FROM foods WHERE id = '$buttonname'";
    mysqli_query($con , $sql);
}
?>
```

When I run this code, only the first ID which is `1` $buttonname reads. But I need all IDs.

Comment: insufficient information ! update with full information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what you mean by "only the first ID which is '1' $buttonname reads" but maybe the problem could be here:

you are first looping all the results every time you load the page.

So when you result is 2 records with for example ids 1 and 2, the values for the input will be name='1' and name='2', but the variable `$buttonname` will be 2 after the loop on every page load.

Then `$_POST[$buttonname]` will become  `$_POST["2"]`, which will be [casted to an integer](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) like `$_POST[2]`.

So if you have this check:

```
`if (isset($_POST[$buttonname])) {`
```

this will read as

```
`if (isset($_POST[2])) {`
```

When you click the first button, the `$_POST` will look like:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Add to Collection
)
```

And for the second button:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Add to Collection
)
```

So as you can see, the if statement will only match the last input element and the first will result in:

> Notice:  Undefined offset: 2

Hope that this helps you solve your problem.

Comment: you get my point but sorry I dont get your answer T_T can you please elaborate what should I do step by step? :(

Comment: I think that you want to insert data into your database using `$buttonname` as the id. The id you need is in the `name` attribute (name="1" etc..) which will become the key for the `$_POST` arrray. A possibility would be to use [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to find your key by searching for the value "Add to Collection" like `$inputName = array_search("Add to Collection", $_POST); if (false !== $inputName) {}`. You should also consider sanitizing the values when you are  using them like this in your sql for possible sql injections.

Answer (score 0):

You write php variables as html code 
Change

```
echo strtoupper("<div class='L-TITLE'>$lhtitle</div>");
echo "<img style = 'width:100%;' src='images/$lhimage' alt='no image inserted'>";
echo "<form action='' method='POST'><input type ='submit' value='Add to Collection' name = '$buttonname'";
```

To

```
echo strtoupper("<div class='L-TITLE'>".$lhtitle."</div>");
echo "<img style = 'width:100%;' src='images/".$lhimage."' alt='no image inserted'>";
echo "<form action='' method='POST'><input type ='submit' value='Add to Collection' name = '".$buttonname."'";
```

Comment: thanks. But my main problem still a problem.   

if (isset($_POST[$buttonname]))  its still only reading first ID which is '1'